# How to get `Test` objects created by actually logged user?

Tags: django, tastypie

```
class TestResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Test.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'test'
        authorization = Authorization()
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
```

How to get `Test` objects created by actually logged user?

All objects:

> http:// 127.0.0.1:8000/api/test/?format=json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to return resources based on the currently logged in user, you can limit the resources returned by overriding `apply_authorization_limits` on the resource. Setting the current user for a POST is just as easy by overriding `obj_create`.

See: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#creating-per-user-resources for an example.

```
class TestResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Test.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'test'
        authorization = Authorization()
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()

    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        return super(TestResource, self).obj_create(bundle,
            user=bundle.request.user)

    def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
        return object_list.filter(user=request.user)
```